# No app sound in 18.04 , system sound OK, speaker test OK. Firefox NOK, VLC NOK

Tags: sound, firefox, 18.04, pulseaudio, alsa

[image: screenshot of my alsamixer]

I had some updates yesterday and since, no app sound on my 18.04. 
Speaker test works, i her the "left, right" when i change the volume, i can hear the little sound to show the volume has changed. My device is recognized and seems to work but that is as far as it goes.

(DELL LATITUDE E5540 btw)

But Firefox still has no sound, my streaming service has no sound as well.
I removed / purged alsa and pulseaudio, reinstalled them and forced it, rebooted, still NOK.
I cannot find anything relative to 18.04 or might have searched badly.

Thanks to everyone for future help.

EDIT 15/07/2018:
Still no sound from my Firefox and Stremio, sound from online radios in rhythmbox OK. Same issue on Google Chrome

```
pacmd
Welcome to PulseAudio 11.1! Use "help" for usage information.
>>> list-sinks
2 sink(s) available.
    index: 0
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_03.0.hdmi-stereo-extra1>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: HARDWARE DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: RUNNING
    suspend cause: 
    priority: 9030
    volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
            balance 0,00
    base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 25,01 ms
    max request: 4 KiB
    max rewind: 64 KiB
    monitor source: 0
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 48000Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 1
    linked by: 1
    configured latency: 25,00 ms; range is 0,50 .. 341,33 ms
    card: 0 <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_03.0>
    module: 7
    properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "HDMI 1"
        alsa.id = "HDMI 1"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "7"
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel HDMI"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel HDMI at 0xf7c34000 irq 48"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:03.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "0a0c"
        device.product.name = "Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "hdmi:0,1"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "65536"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "32768"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "hdmi-stereo-extra1"
        device.profile.description = "Digital Stereo (HDMI 2)"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio Digital Stereo (HDMI 2)"
        alsa.mixer_name = "Intel Haswell HDMI"
        alsa.components = "HDA:80862807,80860101,00100000"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    ports:
        hdmi-output-1: HDMI / DisplayPort 2 (priority 5800, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
    active port: <hdmi-output-1>
  * index: 1
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: SUSPENDED
    suspend cause: IDLE 
    priority: 9039
    volume: front-left: 61884 /  94% / -1,49 dB,   front-right: 61884 /  94% / -1,49 dB
            balance 0,00
    base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 0,00 ms
    max request: 0 KiB
    max rewind: 0 KiB
    monitor source: 1
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 0
    linked by: 0
    configured latency: 0,00 ms; range is 0,50 .. 371,52 ms
    card: 1 <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0>
    module: 8
    properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "ALC3226 Analog"
        alsa.id = "ALC3226 Analog"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.card = "1"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xf7c30000 irq 47"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1b.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "9c20"
        device.product.name = "8 Series HD Audio Controller"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "front:1"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "65536"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "32768"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
        device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo"
        alsa.mixer_name = "Realtek ALC3226"
        alsa.components = "HDA:10ec0292,102805e0,00100001"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    ports:
        analog-output-lineout: Line Out (priority 9900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:

        analog-output-speaker: Speakers (priority 10000, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-speakers"
        analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority 9000, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
    active port: <analog-output-speaker>
>>> ^C
```

Comment: Have you checked to make sure that pulseaudio is actually running?

Comment: Hello,Thank you for your reply :
newton@Newton5540:~$ pulseaudio
E: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: pa_pid_file_create() failed.
I can also listen to online radios from Rythmbox, but still youtube or stremio/netflix don't work! :(

Comment: Have you seen this answer? https://askubuntu.com/a/260035/139735

Comment: Thanks again, i tried the kill and start pulseaudio commands, still no sound from Firefox or Strmio / Netflix. When i change the osund i can hear the small "pop" showing how much the sound has changed.. i try to uninstall firefox but it cretes another issue E:/ package not founf Firefox... :(

Answer (score 3):

I have a similar issue. I also did not have sound from apps, but I had system sounds. I think the problem comes from turning off the computer with HDMI cable still connected and removing it only afterward.

I solved that issue by reconnecting HDMI cable, setting sound source from analog and restarting the computer with HDMI cable connected. After that,  the sound returned and I removed HDMI cable.

My system is Ubuntu 18.04 with all updates.

Comment: This fixed it for me, though no restart required. Just plugged in hdmi, switched the setting, and unplugged hdmi. Audio fixed

Comment: This has worked for me in the past but im now on holiday without an HDMI cable handy... #FML

Answer (score 3):

Had a similar issue. I was able to fiddle around in *pacmd* to redirect sound output from *HDMI* to *analog-output*:

1. Play sound through the trouble application (Firefox in Solid Snakes case) and leave it running in the background.
2. Open Pulse Audio via the terminal

   ```
   pacmd
   ```
3. list your sinks inputs, the trouble applications' sink should be HDMI , ie.

   ```
   $ list-sink-inputs   
   1 sink input(s) available.
      index: 134
      driver: <protocol-native.c>
         flags: START_CORKED 
         state: RUNNING
         sink: 0 <alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo-extra5>
   ```
4. Move the application sound output device via the `move-sink-input` command. The `list-sinks` command returned the index of my `analog-output` as `1`, so

   ```
   move-sink-input 134 1
   ```
5. You should now be enjoying sweet sounds, well done!

If you get stuck, type `help` from inside `pacmd`

There is also the `set-default-sink` command. The `stat` command's output can be used to verify your default sink.

Comment: This did work for me.great

Answer (score 1):

This is strange.
I installed Pulse Audio Volume Control AGAIN. 
I had to start a video on youtube via Firefox.
In the Playback tab, i saw the AudioIPCServer with the Firefox icon and there the output was set to Built-in Audio ( HDMI )
I just had to choose Analog output and the sound was back.
I hope it will help other Ubunters.
Did i not get any answers because my question was too "dumb"?
Thanks anyway.